# The size limitation of .bss/.data section in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I just added a 56,212 byte array (declare, not dynamically allocate) to one of device driver (driver is built-in) in Linux 2.6.15 at ARM platform, and always get kernel panic after issue the commands related to process ID (e.g. ps or top) even if that device driver is not running.

Here is the backtrace,

```
[<c009be04>] (pid_revalidate+0x0/0xa8) from [<c007b934>] (do_lookup+0x18c/0x1b8)
 r5 = C5CA9F70  r4 = 00000000 
[<c007b7a8>] (do_lookup+0x0/0x1b8) from [<c007c380>] (__link_path_walk+0x8b8/0xd78)
[<c007bac8>] (__link_path_walk+0x0/0xd78) from [<c007c8c4>] (link_path_walk+0x84/0x134)
[<c007c840>] (link_path_walk+0x0/0x134) from [<c007cb10>] (path_lookup+0x19c/0x1a8)
 r7 = C48E1000  r6 = 00000000  r5 = C487E000  r4 = C487FF14
[<c007c974>] (path_lookup+0x0/0x1a8) from [<c007cc08>] (__path_lookup_intent_open+0x4c/0x8c)
 r7 = 00000001  r6 = C487FF14  r5 = C48E1000  r4 = 00000001
[<c007cbbc>] (__path_lookup_intent_open+0x0/0x8c) from [<c007cc64>] (path_lookup_open+0x1c/0x20)
 r7 = 00000005  r6 = 00000004  r5 = C487FF14  r4 = 00000000
[<c007cc48>] (path_lookup_open+0x0/0x20) from [<c007d45c>] (open_namei+0x7c/0x67c)
[<c007d3e0>] (open_namei+0x0/0x67c) from [<c006d28c>] (filp_open+0x2c/0x48)
[<c006d260>] (filp_open+0x0/0x48) from [<c006d55c>] (do_sys_open+0x44/0xd0)
 r5 = 00000000  r4 = 00000000 
[<c006d518>] (do_sys_open+0x0/0xd0) from [<c006d5f8>] (sys_open+0x10/0x14)
[<c006d5e8>] (sys_open+0x0/0x14) from [<c0020e00>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
```

If I decrease the volume of array to 56,208 bytes, everything is OK.

The "readelf" result of 56,208 bytes array (OK case)

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        c0008000 008000 018000 00 WAX  0   0 32
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        c0020000 020000 24c7f4 00  AX  0   0 32
  [ 3] .text.init        PROGBITS        c026c7f4 26c7f4 000078 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 4] .pci_fixup        PROGBITS        c026c86c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 5] .rio_route        PROGBITS        c026c86c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 6] __ksymtab         PROGBITS        c026c86c 26c86c 004458 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 7] __ksymtab_gpl     PROGBITS        c0270cc4 270cc4 000898 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 8] __kcrctab         PROGBITS        c027155c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 9] __kcrctab_gpl     PROGBITS        c027155c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [10] __ksymtab_strings PROGBITS        c027155c 27155c 00b288 00   A  0   0  4
  [11] __param           PROGBITS        c027c7e4 27c7e4 000618 00   A  0   0  4
  [12] .data             PROGBITS        c027e000 27e000 08c6f0 00  WA  0   0 32
  [13] .bss              NOBITS          c030a700 30a700 0248e8 00  WA  0   0 32
  [14] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 30a700 0028c8 00      0   0  1
  [15] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 30cfc8 0000a0 00      0   0  1
  [16] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 30d338 07aa50 10     17 25869  4
  [17] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 387d88 057629 00      0   0  1
```

The "readelf" result of 56,212 bytes array (NG case)

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .init             PROGBITS        c0008000 008000 018000 00 WAX  0   0 32
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        c0020000 020000 24c7f4 00  AX  0   0 32
  [ 3] .text.init        PROGBITS        c026c7f4 26c7f4 000078 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 4] .pci_fixup        PROGBITS        c026c86c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 5] .rio_route        PROGBITS        c026c86c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 6] __ksymtab         PROGBITS        c026c86c 26c86c 004458 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 7] __ksymtab_gpl     PROGBITS        c0270cc4 270cc4 000898 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 8] __kcrctab         PROGBITS        c027155c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [ 9] __kcrctab_gpl     PROGBITS        c027155c 30a700 000000 00   W  0   0  1
  [10] __ksymtab_strings PROGBITS        c027155c 27155c 00b288 00   A  0   0  4
  [11] __param           PROGBITS        c027c7e4 27c7e4 000618 00   A  0   0  4
  [12] .data             PROGBITS        c027e000 27e000 08c6f0 00  WA  0   0 32
  [13] .bss              NOBITS          c030a700 30a700 024908 00  WA  0   0 32
  [14] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 30a700 0028c8 00      0   0  1
  [15] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 30cfc8 0000a0 00      0   0  1
  [16] .symtab           SYMTAB          00000000 30d338 07aa50 10     17 25869  4
  [17] .strtab           STRTAB          00000000 387d88 057629 00      0   0  1
```

The differences between two cases is just the size of .bss. (OK case is 248e8; NG case is 24908)

I was wondering whether I have violated some rules in Linux kernel, or I am debugging in the wrong way?

Comment: Why are you sure that the problem is with bss size and not with your code? It could be a hidden error in your code, which is revealed only in a specific scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, your bss goes 8 bytes on the page frame 0x32Fxxx (if the page size is 4K). It might be you got a page fault that can't be handled by one or another reason, in particular, as @Tsyvarev mentioned, a bug in the code.